# implement web service with wsdl in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, ios5, wsdl

In my application i have to implement web service.and want to login with it.there are some parameters and method in it which are as below:

```
Parameter: mailaddress String with @   
password String  
Return: If ok, then you receive a loginToken. (> 0)  
If not ok, then loginToken < 0  
-1 = user not found    
-2 = wrong password  
When you can not reach the server, you have to inform the user in dialog, with “Server not available”. In the cases -1 or -2 you should inform the user.
```

the web service is in wsdl format and i don't know how to use it.
Suppose there is a link http://google.com    so how can i do login    please help

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the framework , we can use

[pico](https://github.com/bulldog2011/pico) - A light iOS web service client framework.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://maniacdev.com/2012/01/tool-soap-based-web-services-made-easy-on-ios
this post explained how to consume wsdl services. its has 2 example projects too.